How to correctly assign a python variable to a API key value
A partial API request response is:
{
    "quoteResponse": {
        "error": null,
        "result": [
            {
                "ask": 209.94,
                "askSize": 2,
                "averageAnalystRating": "2.0 - Buy",
                "averageDailyVolume10Day": 119050820,
                "averageDailyVolume3Month": 67794775,
                "bid": 207.01,
                "bidSize": 30,
                "bookValue": 4.837,
                "cryptoTradeable": false,
                        }
        ]
    }
} 

Trying to assign "Ask" value to a variable (X).
Base code to form json is:
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
API_Data = response.json()

API_Data = (json.dumps(API_Data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
print(API_Data)

I have tried two code methods to assign key value for "ask" to a variable (X) as follows:
Method 1:
for key in API_Data:
    if key == 'ask':
        X = API_Data[key]

print("ask" = ",X)

Method 2:
for item in API_Data:
   X = (item['quoteResponse']['result']['ask'])

print("ask" = ",X)


You aren't forming JSON. Calling the json method retrieves the body of the response and immediately decodes it, returning an ordinary Python dict.

You're looping over top level elements, which is only quoteResponse. Instead just extract that.
Then, results is a list, so you'll need to index or loop over that then get the ask
API_Data = response.json()
results = API_Data['quoteResponse']['result']
x = results[0]["ask"]

This assumes that the request returned successfully, and that results list always has at least one element. You should check the response status code and error element as a best practice

Thanks for quick response.  However, after trying this exact code I received the following error:      results = API_Data['quoteResponse']['result']
~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Remove API_Data = (json.dumps(API_Data line

Perfect!!!  Thank you very much.  Solved my mental block.
